# Remove "Deploying to <environment>" text GitHub Actions

Tags: github-actions

[image]

As I'm using the environment feature only for handling .env files in different environments and I'm not deploying, I'd like to remove the "Deploying to production" text as it's misleading. Is there a way to remove the progress bar and the text from the workflow UI?